# How to add bottom border to text in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have some text in Word:

[image]

And i want some portion to have a bottom border:

[image]

So performing the obvious action (and the action [documented by Microsoft in KB 145149](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/145149/wd-how-to-create-ruling-lines-or-blank-underlines-in-word)), i select to apply a **Bottom Border**:

[image]

But rather than applying a bottom border, it applies all **Outside Borders**:

[image]

The reason i know it's all *"Outside Border"*, is because Word tells me:

[image]

How do i place a line under text in Word (2010, 64-bit, Windows 10, on a Friday)?

### Bonus Reading

- [WD: How to Create Ruling Lines or Blank Underlines in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/145149/wd-how-to-create-ruling-lines-or-blank-underlines-in-word)
- [Adding Borders to Paragraphs](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T008698_Adding_Borders_to_Paragraphs.html)
- [Applying Borders and Shading](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2030049&seqNum=15)

Comment: As the KB article that you linked to states, the border method that you're trying to use for individual parts of a paragraph works for whole paragraphs only. Did you try applying underlining to spaces (or tab spaces), setting a tab leader, or inserting a drawing object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just using the underline?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a bottom (or any single edge) border to text in Microsoft Word.  Instead, use underline.

Regular text has only one border.  The following macro confirms.

```
MsgBox Selection.Font.Borders.Count
```

As stated below, a Paragraph has four borders (left, right, top, bottom).

```
MsgBox Selection.Sections(1).Borders.Count
```

> [Borders Object (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198054.aspx)
>
> The number of members in the Borders collection is finite and varies
>   depending on the type of object. For example, a table has six elements
>   in the Borders collection, whereas a paragraph has four.

Answer (score 1):

You can add just a top border or bottom border to a paragraph in MS word; but most annoyingly this feature does not work unless you first select a whole paragraph. then you can select the "top border" or whatever from the menu options.
If you've just selected a line of the paragraph, or a word or two, you'll get a full box round whatever you selected.

This is very annoying, and it took me a frustrating while to work out why I kept getting a full border instead of a top border.

Answer (score 0):

If you highlight the word(s) and then go to Font you can change 'underline style',so you can adjust the style and the colour. Simples!